# Encountered unsupported property Indexdocument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

- I am deploying and configuring AWS CloudFront using a yaml file
- I receive a message that stated "Encountered unsupported property Indexdocument"

This is the code from my yaml file and the block code. I am following the [Cloud Resume Challenge](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEk97Q5Nj5oesA1WNk7DzaUpZUnCsQFVQ) instructional guide on how to complete the cloud resume challenge.

```
Resources:
  MyWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Public Read
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        Indexdocument: index.html
      BucketName: mcderkaderkas-first-website
  

  MyDistribution:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ViewProtocolPolicy: allow-all
          TargetOriginId: http://mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
          DefaultTTL: 0
          MinTTL: 0
          MaxTTL: 0
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
        Origins:
          - DomainName: http://mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            Id: http://mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
        Enabled: "true"
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
```

> CloudFormation events from stack operations (refresh every 0.5 seconds)

---

### ResourceStatus                                     ResourceType                                       LogicalResourceId                                  ResourceStatusReason

### UPDATE_FAILED                                      AWS::S3::Bucket                                    MyWebsite                                          Encountered unsupported property Indexdocument
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                        AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                         cloud-resume-challenge                             The following resource(s) failed to update:
[MyWebsite].
UPDATE_COMPLETE                                    AWS::S3::Bucket                                    MyWebsite                                          -
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS       AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                         cloud-resume-challenge                             -
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE                           AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                         cloud-resume-challenge                             -

Error: Failed to create/update the stack: cloud-resume-challenge, Waiter StackUpdateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation generally provides pretty decent documentation on what to pass where, including for an [S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html)'s [website configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration.html).

In this case I can see you specify a key `Indexdocument` while the documentation capitalizes `Document` ie [`IndexDocument`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration.html#cfn-s3-websiteconfiguration-indexdocument).  Yaml, cloudformation, and nearly everything else involving computers is case sensitive (notable exceptions include windows / mac os filesystems with default settings, DNS, and email addresses ).  So make sure to get that case right in your Yaml files!